connecting from a container to a neighboring container
I have an avi container that was created in this way (launching new containers from a container) :
FROM lukemathwalker/cargo-chef:latest-rust-1.75.0-alpine3.18 as chef
WORKDIR /app

FROM chef AS planner
COPY . .
RUN cargo chef prepare --recipe-path recipe.json

FROM chef AS builder
COPY --from=planner /app/recipe.json recipe.json
RUN cargo chef cook --release --recipe-path recipe.json
COPY . .
RUN cargo build --release

FROM alpine:3.18
RUN apk update && apk add docker-cli
COPY --from=builder /app/target/release/blue_traktor_api /
VOLUME /var/run/docker.sock
ENV DOCKER_HOST unix:///var/run/docker.sock
CMD ["./blue_traktor_api"]

I get the address of a neighboring container from the joker and I have an address relative to the host (port), but how do I get a direct link to it relative to the api container without creating a network and adding content to the same network?

Containers can't communicate with each other unless they're on the same network.  You need to make sure both containers are on the same network.  There are API calls to dynamically create networks and attach containers too, but I might prefer an approach where the program takes the network name as an option.  (If you can restructure your application to avoid needing to dynamically create containers, it will be much simpler.)

After I threw docker.sock into the api container, the creation of containers remained using the same commands as outside it :
let Ok(output) = Command::new("docker")
                .args(&[
                    "run",
                    "-d",
                    "--restart", "always",
                    "-p",
                    &format!("{}:27017", port),
                    "--name",
                    container_name,
                    "mongo:latest",
                ])
                .stdout(Stdio::null())
                .stderr(Stdio::null())
                .output()

to create an address to another container, I got an ip address:
 let output = Command::new("docker")
        .args(&["inspect", "-f", "{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}", container_name])
        .output()?;

and getting the port:
 let output = Command::new("docker")
            .args(&["inspect", "-f", "{{range $key, $value := .HostConfig.PortBindings}}{{printf \"%s\\n\" (index (split $key \"/\") 0)}}{{end}}", container_name])
            .output()?;

it began to look like this:
mongodb://172.17.0.2:6379

everything is connected successfully via the link
